# Obito's Clothes Affected by Kamui?

Tags: naruto

Obito's MS allows him to be intangible. But when it attacks, his clothes don't get damaged at all (or fall off of him).

If we take the assumption that things really close to him or in contact with him are also affected by Kamui, does that mean that a person holding him or a backpack he's wearing is also intangible?

Clothes has always been a plot hole in Naruto. Like how Madara magically gets new clothes when he becomes SSOP. Or when the head Pain gets wrecked so hard by Naruto, but his clothes only get somewhat torn.

Answer (score 6):

*Does that mean that a person holdings with him or a backpack he's wearing is also intangible?* Yes, anything touching the individual who uses the Kamui is also affected by the justu

[Kamui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBLi.jpg)

> **Right Eye**
>
> Obito's right eye uses a short-range version of Kamui, which can only transport targets in close proximity to the user; physical contact with the target is seemingly required
>
> ...
>
> This intangibility can be extended to anything the user is touching at the moment of activation

**Anything** that is touching the caster becomes intangible, including clothes.

In Naruto Manga Chapter 684, we see Obito instructing Naruto and Sakura to keep their hands on his person so they may teleport alongside Obito

[image: [1]: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/]